# Opening G Suite Marketplace Apps from Gmail is not working and getting 502 error

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

When I am accessing G Suite Marketplace apps from GMail menu, it is getting 502 error page from (apis.google.com) and url format is: 
https://apis.google.com/additnow/l?applicationid={GCP_projectId}&__ls=ogb&__lu={Application_entry_url }

I am also able to access my application with direct url but the issue is from GMail to universal tab access of G Suite Marketplace Apps.

G Suite Marketplace apps from GMail:
[image]

Below are screenshots of error page:
[image]
[image]

I have already raised an issue on Google issue Tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128469607

Please reply me why is this occurring? in GMAIL

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report. The issue should be fixed now, if that's not the case please let me know.

Comment: I have seen that Google marked as Fixed in Google issue Tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128469607. But I want know why this issue came ? Thanks.